# Exit but still saving even when user selects to cancel

Tags: excel, vba, save, msgbox

I have an odd thing (I think) but probably doing something incorrectly here. I am trying to force the user to enter in certain information in excel. The msgbox comes up with the OK/Cancel buttons but when either is selected the workbook saves and exits. If they cancel then I want it to sit on the cell where the issue is. Any help would be appreciated

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    
    '---------------------------
    '-- Missing Employee Name --
    '---------------------------
    If Cells(5, 2).Value = Empty Then
        If Not MsgBox("Employee Name missing! Pressing OK will exit without saving.", vbOKCancel, "The Mill") = vbOK Then
            With Sheets("sheet1")
                .Activate
                .Cells(5, 2).Activate
            End With
            Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If 

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code will not consider the "OK" button a `True` condition. For considering it `True`, you must remove `Not` from `If Not MsgBox(...`. Then, you should eliminate `Exit Sub`. Let the event interpreting the `Cancel` option.

Comment: I removed the "Exit Sub" and let it drop through but it still did the same thing. If I don't press OK then isn't that stating that it is not cancelled so Cancel is set to False as a default?

Comment: For the OK button now it exits w/o saving... Thanks FaneDuru for the tip. On the cancel I want the excel to remain open and position at the cell that is needing attention. In this case the employee name is missing.  Currently it exits w/o saving instead of moving to "Sheet1" to that cell location.

Comment: I like to believe that I understood it from the beginning... That's why I made those suggestions. Glad I could help, anyhow!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you aren't handling `Workbook_BeforeClose`, which triggers as you try to close the workbook.
So while the save is canceled, the close is not.

Moving everything to `Workbook_BeforeClose` and handling it there kind of works, until the user saves manually. So you will still have to handle that in the before save event.

This is an example:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
If Cells(5, 2).Value = Empty Then
    If MsgBox("Employee Name missing! Pressing OK will exit without saving.", vbOKCancel, "The Mill") = vbOK Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.Quit
    Else
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 2).Activate
        Cancel = True
    End If
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
If Cells(5, 2).Value = Empty Then
    Cancel = True
    MsgBox "Employee Name missing!"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 2).Activate
End If
End Sub
```

The only caveat I have seen, is that `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` will affect other open workbooks.